# Не работает команда start в cmder

Tags: windows

Установила cmder для работы с гитом, в настройках меняла только отображение задач по умолчанию на bash:bash. При попытке открыть какие-либо папки/файлы командой start, появляется ошибка:  C:/cmder/vendor/git-for-windows/usr/bin/start: line 8: cmd: command not found
В чем проблема?

Comment: Ну а можно листинг-то скрипта? Чё там в 8й строке не нравится?

Comment: вот 8 строка, единственная во всем файле: cmd //c start "${@//&/^&}